# Add image to a customtkinter checkbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox, customtkinter

Trying to make a login page (using `customtkinter`). Finished most of the code but when it came to show password I wanted to add a image to the checkbox.

This is the checkbox I'm trying to add the image to:

```python
entry2 = ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame1, width=220, placeholder_text="Password", show="*", font=('Segoe Ui', 17))
entry2.pack(padx=10, pady=12)
entry2.place(relx=0.5, rely=login_form_y + 0.06, anchor=ctk.CENTER)

cb_va = ctk.IntVar(value=0)

def my_show():
    if cb_va.get() != 0:
        entry2.configure(show='')
    else:
        entry2.configure(show='*')

checkbox1 = ctk.CTkCheckBox(master=frame1, width=220, text="Show Password", font=('Segoe Ui', 12), variable=cb_va, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=my_show)
checkbox1.pack(padx=10, pady=12)
checkbox1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.62, anchor=ctk.CENTER)
```

So I wanted to change the check mark of the checkbox to an eye image but there is no image function in the customtkinter checkbox

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and the error that you get.

Comment: It's unclear. Do you want to customize the check mark of the checkbox? Or do you want to add a image label left or right of the checkbox? For the former, CustomTkinter doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. To fix it I made a modification to the base class that solved the problem.

I uploaded the code [here](https://github.com/bulaya-ute/ImageCheckBox_customtkinter/tree/main)

The above class will get the job done! Here's an example of it being used:

[[image: Side by side comparison of a log in form with a checkbox in the "ticked" and "unticked" states, but a small graphic of an eye and a crossed-out eye replace the usual check mark/empty box.]]